# Creat Hyperlink For Footer in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So i want to create hyperlinks for my footer which will redirect me to specific links first i used Link but it gives me an error telling me that i cannot use Link outside the Router so help me with that here is my current footer component.

```
import React from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCopyright } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { Row, Col, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import logo from '../assets/SE-logo.png';

export const Footer = () => (

    <div style={{marginTop:'1em', width:'100%'}}>
        <Container fluid>
        <Row>
            <Col md lg>
            <div id="footerFD">
                <p style={{fontSize:"40px", fontWeight:"500", color:"#fb7840"}}>Got a project?<br/>
                <span style={{fontSize:"30px", fontWeight:"300", color:"#fff"}}>We want to hear about it.</span></p>
                <div id="footerSD">
                    <Row>
                        <Col lg md id="colF">
                            <Row>
                                <Col-4 md lg>
                                <p style={{fontSize:"20px", fontWeight:"300"}}> (+789) 132 4657</p>
                                </Col-4>
                                <Col md lg>
                                <p style={{fontSize:"20px", fontWeight:"300"}}>example@example.com</p>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </div>
            </div>
            </Col>
            <Col md lg>
                <div id="footerFD2">
                    <div>
                        <img src={logo} alt="logo" id="footerLogo"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="footerSD2">
                        <Row>
                            <Col md lg><p>Home</p></Col>
                            <Col md lg><p>Services</p></Col>
                            <Col md lg><p>Projects</p></Col>
                            <Col md lg><p>Contact</p></Col>
                        </Row>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Col>
        </Row>
        </Container>
        <p style={{marginTop:'1em', width:'100%', textAlign:'center'}}>Developed By <span style={{color:'#fb7840'}}>Hassan Uddin Sheikh</span><br/>All Rights Reserved <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCopyright}/> 2020</p>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your app in `browser router` like so:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

The `link` cannot stand on its own without a `browser router` wrapper somewhere higher up.

Reference: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter

Answer (score 0):

I use `Nav.Link` instead and it works

```
<Nav>
    <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link href="/"></Nav.Link>
    <Nav.Item>
</Nav>
```

Comment: You will have to wrap every link like that in the app if you go with that approach. Isn't that inefficient? Plus if you ever make a menu, you won't be able to switch routes easily.